# Power BI. Sort a column with repeated values based on another column

Tags: sorting, powerbi, crosstab

For my requirement, I've got a specific layout for a report.  To simplify, the series of Categories should present the Areas in a particular order (financial information).

[image]

Every Category will be present on a different Page on Power BI. However, as you can see, some areas belong to multiple Categories.  Because of this, I'm getting an error message if I try to order this column by an index,  and I can't modify the name of the area.
[image]

Is it possible to specify on a cross table that I do not need it to perform any alphabetic order?

[image]

I've looked for a possible answer, but so far I have not found any solution to this.

Regards.

Comment: You should not use an index, you need to make sure your Areas have unique values, C= 1, D=2, E=3, you have in your example E as 1 and 4

Comment: That is right. That area belongs to two different categories and has to be shown in a particular order in each one of the, that is why I have created an index: to force that order.